# iPhone 5 and 5s lock screen flashing Apple logo

Tags: iphone

We have three iPhones in my house: two 5's and one 5s. Over the past 6 months every few weeks they glitch. What happens is that at exactly midnight eastern time all three phones start showing the lock screen for two seconds, followed by a second of a black screen, followed by five seconds of the Apple logo on a white background. During this time the phone is running. When on the lock screen you can actually swipe left and start entering your unlock code, but you will get interrupted. This usually goes on for at least 6 hours. Hard resetting the phone does not fix it: you just boot to the same state. Restoring from a backup does fix it and seems to be the recommended solution on the Apple forums.

If I do not do a restore from backup, the problem resolves itself usually by around 10am.

This happened with all iOS 7 updates including the 7.0.4.

This is a huge problem. First, it lights up the whole room and drains the battery. If not on the charger, the phone will die and our alarms will not go off. If on the charger, the phone will keep buzzing like you just plugged it in. BTW, we use standard Apple cables and chargers. Restoring from backup takes a long time and I do not wish to do that for three phones in the middle of the night. There are of course other inconveniences, like not being able to dial 911.

Someone please tell me I am not alone in having this issue. It seems like a huge bug in iOS and in just a bit I am going to try to call Apple to see if I can figure out how to report it. In the meantime, I'd just like to see if the three iPhones in my house are the only ones that are experiencing this or if this is widespread.

Edit: Turns out an iPad Air we have also had the same problem. The only iOS device that did not is a third generation iPad.

Edit 2: Just called Apple. Their senior support person has never heard of this issue, so they are escalating to the development team. We'll see what they say...

Edit 3: Have not experienced the same issue but never heard back from Apple. Seems like the 7.1 update helped. If anyone else is still experiencing this issue, please respond.

Comment: Did you try disabling the auto updates?

Comment: I have not. Is that what you think does it?

Comment: It sounds like it, the only way to find out what is going on your phones is to disable the all auto updates.

Comment: Are your devices jailbroken? Or are they running the standard iOS7?

Comment: None are jailbroken or have ever been. Hmm. I am open to trying to disable auto-updates to rule out if that's what's causing the issue, but I am not willing to accept that as Apple's official solution to the problem.

Comment: Would the newest update of 7.1.0 fix any bugs??

Comment: The changelog includes something about a "fix for a homescreen crash". Not sure if this is it, but I updated the devices. We'll see if the problem comes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same problem. It has to do with recurring calendar events. This mainly occurs when the phone is syncing with Microsoft Exchange, but may occur in other circumstances. You need to find any recurring calendar events and simply delete them. Adding an end date will not fix the problem. It took me about a month of looking through device logs to figure this out.

Comment: Are you sure this was the culprit? In either case, this doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: This is the issue. I'm an iOS developer and I have been working with Apple engineering to identify the issue. They have tried numerous times to fix the issue, but the issue is on Microsoft's end.

Comment: Could you provide some context? You are still experiencing the screen lock symptoms like I described above? Also, how could this be an issue with Microsoft? An Apple product freezes up when given what you seem to describe as bad data. I don't care where the data comes from, the entire OS shouldn't have an issue because of a bug in the calendar app.

Comment: Sorry if I was being somewhat vague. This issue was actually occurring on my mother's phone, but yes, she is still having the issue. The problem lies within the fact that Microsoft's software responds with a expiration date that is never. This is beyond the realm of the 32 bit iOS (even the 64 bit iPhone 5S) and it causes what is called an integer overload. This causes the operating system to crash repeatedly until it can sort itself out. I do agree that Apple should catch for this, but the attempts to do so have failed thus far. iOS 7.1.2 was just released though, so that might fix it.

Comment: Deleting the recurring calendar events will solve the problem as a temporary measure though.

Comment: This seems plausible, though without seeing the code I can't tell with 100% certainty. Do you know if there is any public discussion with Apple that can be linked to for anyone who finds this page? I am going to accept your answer but I think the question remains open-ended.

Comment: There is nothing public (Apple Bug Reporter), but if I receive any additional information for Apple engineering or find anything out for myself, I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you check my video :https://youtu.be/XVLmDV_Kchc

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like a clever solution to get the iPhone to think that it's overheating to get it to reset. I can no longer reproduce the problem (since a much older iOS update), so I cannot confirm that it would fix the issue I was having. The screen pattern I was seeing was not the same as in this video.